# How to observe infinity?

Tags: combinatorics, analysis, infinity, constructive-mathematics

In my calculus course, there's example stated on the book:

Given that $M$ is an ordered set and the sequence $\{a_n\}\subset M$, prove that there's a (weakly) monotonic subsequence of $\{a_n\}$.

After some searching work, I realized that it's a special case (Hint: the color of $(j,k)$ depends on whether $a_j\le a_k$) of [infinite Ramsey's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem#Infinite_Ramsey_theorem), well, and to my surprise, the finite one is implied in the infinite one. I read these two proofs. They are actually concise and graceful.

However, I cannot appreciate the aspect or essence of these two proofs. Observing more closely, I find that these proofs of infinite Ramsey's theorem use both constructive technique and non-constructive technique. For example, pigeonhole principle is non-constructive:

If $A\cup B$ is infinite, then $A$ is infinite or $B$ is infinite.

It seems that we cannot construct the infinite subset of $A$ or $B$ explicitly by the infiniteness of $A\cup B$. In the proof of infinite Ramsey's theorem, pigeonhole principle is used, but it's not the only technique. We should mention that sequence $\{a_n\}$ is constructed explicitly.

Now my question arises: How can we observe the infinity? How can we conceive these proofs on our owns? Maybe it's more a question about methodology and how to solve problems.

Thanks!

Comment: Look deeply into the night sky.

Comment: You should note that why the pigeonhole principle is not constructive, it follows from a very basic understanding that the union of two finite sets is finite. Therefore in splitting an infinite set into two, at least one of the parts has to be infinite.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm not sure whether I used the right word. I consider that writing a set explicitly or inductively is constructive. For example, if $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}\subset U$, then $U$ is infinite, or inductively, just like the proof in wikipedia, it writes $a_1,a_2,\ldots$ one by one. At first, I've been thinking how to prove infinite Ramsey theorem by writing $M=\{m_1,m_2,\ldots\}$ explicitly, but failed.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Your proof of pigeonhole principle is reductio ad absurdum. I don't think it's constructive.

Comment: I don't see a proof anywhere. I also think that mathematics in which you can split an infinite set into two parts and both of them are finite is plain wrong (philosophically).

Comment: @AsafKaragila It's really **evident** but I think obvious things could be complicated in a intricate problem because we don't really **understand** these obvious stuff. At least, for me, infinite Ramsey theorem is so hard.